# Database for Raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, android, home-automation, web, database

I'm working on Home Automation project using Raspberry pi and i'm making android app for controlling home appliances like fan and bulb. I also want to make website for admin to see status of appliances, Which online database should i use for this purpose? i have to use database for app and website too.

Comment: Hi again Umer. This question is not really Pi specific. It is more software development orientated. It will probably get closed. It all depends on the programming language you are going to use. I suppose Python? I myself am a DotNet guy and ASPNET Core works well on Linux now too. Anyway, you can use any database you want. There are a ton of libraries for all major providers. It also depends what features you want. Relational, document, graph, text? You should probably do some research. A quick way is to use sqlite on the Pi (this is relational) but you can also run Mongo (document)

Comment: For your purposes (a DB that manage IoT devices in a home), I expect the DB size won't huge, wont have issues such as lots of complex table relationships, wont have lots of rows with empty space, etc.  For this reason... you can use either a relational SQL database such as MySQL or MariaDB (MariaDB is a fork of MySQL) ... or you can use a NoSQL database such as MongoDB.

You'll need to make sure there's a distro that works on the OS of your choice (e.g. you can run MariaDB on Raspbian.)